# Why does this geometry say "Nothing selected"?

Tags: edit-mode, geometry

I'm modelling a character that is all one mesh.

[image: The outliner displaying that the character is one object and one mesh]

When I select the body of the character, I'm able to move it around, but when I select the pants, I can't move them.

[image: The body moves, but the pants don't.]

I've also noted that the Item menu says "Nothing selected" when the pants are selected. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue! Somehow I managed to hide all the vertices without hiding any faces. Unhiding everything with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> fixed the issue for me.